# In dire need of step by step basic oauth signing with YQL, in C#?

Tags: c#, web-services, oauth, yql

I'm trying to get started with oauth signing in yql. I'm trying to get public data, but with the higher limit of 100,000 calls. My interest is in the yahoo finance tables, such as yahoo.finance.historicaldata. I'd like to retrieve the xml for several of the public tables, daily, entirely in automated code via C#. I've asked a similar question before here, and was pointed to the yql docs, which were helpful in getting me a little more familiar with all that's involved.

Like many of the similar posts I've since come across, I can't figure out how to make it work for me. I'm new to web services in general, and using C#. Does anyone have a minute and know- how to give me a step- by step, even if it's somewhat top- down? To give you an idea of where I'm at, I don't know how to get the tokens, and I'm not sure once I get one, if I have to then submit it for every request for the rest of my session. RTFM I know... I've been doing a ton of searching on this, for weeks now. Big thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0):

> I don't know how to get the tokens

- File an [application](https://developer.apps.yahoo.com/dashboard/createKey.html)

> if I have to then submit it for every request for the rest of my session

Here's a basic diagram:

- [oAuth Diagram](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/hh801906.aspx#63843d9d-9e67-492c-b66d-cc4ac66a46fc)

And here's a detailed diagram:

- [Yahoo oAuth diagram](http://developer.yahoo.com/oauth/guide/oauth-auth-flow.html)